# Evaluate multiple boolean columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I wonder if there is smart, pythonic way to evaluate multiple boolean columns in a dataframe at the same time.

Based on the boolean mask of multiple columns (only one column per row contains a true), I want to assign a string value (in the following example, `first_true`, `second_true`, or `third_true` - depending on which column is true).

The following does what it is supposed to do but I think there are more beautiful solutions.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[True, False, False], [False, True, False], [False, False, True]], columns=['b1', 'b2', 'b3'])

df.b1 = df.b1.replace({True: 'first_true', False: None})
df.b2 = df.b2.replace({True: 'second_true', False: None})
df.b3 = df.b3.replace({True: 'third_true', False: None})

df.bfill(axis=1).b1 # returns 
#0     first_true
#1    second_true
#2     third_true
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with mapping columns names:

```
df = df.dot(df.columns.map({'b1':'first_true',
                            'b2':'second_true',
                            'b3':'third_true'}))
print(df)
0     first_true
1    second_true
2     third_true
dtype: object
```

If need dynamic solution use `inflect` for generate strings:

```
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

out = [f"{p.number_to_words(p.ordinal(i))}_true" for i in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1)]
print (out)
['first_true', 'second_true', 'third_true']

df = df.dot(pd.Index(out))
print(df)
0     first_true
1    second_true
2     third_true
dtype: object
```